# SCons generate a runnable jar file including external jar

Tags: java, jar, runnable, packaging, scons

First, I do not understand anything to SCons.
I want to generate a runnable jar file. In Eclipse I do the following:

Export -> Runnable JAR file:

- Select a launch configuration with a `public static void main(String[] args)` method
- Select `Extract required libraries into generated JAR`

This way I get a jar file that includes all the external classes.

So I need to do it with SCons, how should I proceed ?

Thanks

Comment: If you are just building Java, use a gradle, or maven, or some other system than SCons.  Building straight Java projects is SCons' strength.

Comment: Can't choose technology. 
I hate SCons.

Comment: You can't choose to another build system?  O.k. Do you have any SCons logic written thus far?

Comment: Yep, Scons is deeply metastased in our build system. We call a command to build a jar file but this command will generate a normal jar, not a runnable one.

Comment: Can you pastebin the logic you use to create a Jar, there's no reason you can't  do it with SCons, just probably simpler with other Java specific build systems.